# JavaScript can control elements in a panel?

Tags: javascript

I am looking for some sample JavaScript code that will allow me to have a list of N items and to be able to toggle that list between a collapsed top item and an expanded list of all of the items.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like [Treeview](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Treeview)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a a function like:

```
function toggle(itemsInList) {
    for (var i = 0; i < itemsInList.length; ++i) {
        itemsInList[i].style.display = (itemsInList[i].style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
    }

}
```